# Import textfile - list index out of range

Tags: python

```
infile = open("/Users/name/Downloads/points.txt", "r")
line = infile.readline()
while line != "":
    line = infile.readline()
    wordlist = line.split()
    x_co = float(wordlist[0])
    y_co = float(wordlist[1])
```

I looked around but actually didn't find something helpful for my problem.

I have a .txt file with x (first column) and y (second column) coordinates (see picture).
I want every x and y coordinate separated but when I run my code I always get an ERROR:

```
x_co = float(wordList[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for helping!

[image: Textfile with the coordinates]

Comment: 1. you never parse your first line. 2. you check if `line=""` *before* reading and parsing one. What if the very next `readline` is the empty one?

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = "/Users/name/Downloads/points.txt"
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        wordlist = line.split()
        x_co = float(wordlist[0])
        y_co = float(wordlist[1])
```

`with` automatically handles file closing

For more such idiomatic ways in Python, [read this](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/6213790)

Comment: Here is another one: all the inner loop needs is `x_co, y_co = [float(x) for x in line.split()]`

Answer (score 0):

Better you can do this way:

```
infile = open("/Users/name/Downloads/points.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    if line:
        wordlist = line.split()
        x_co = float(wordlist[0])
        y_co = float(wordlist[1])
```

Comment: It seems to work great, but I'm trying to learn from my mistakes. Why I got this error?

Comment: bvdabjorn: See comment by @Rad Lexus under your question for why.

Comment: (Feel free to add your own explanation, as comments can be deleted any time.) Be warned that the line `if line:` is misleading! Even when a line is blank in the file, it will still contain a return. Either remove the entire line (and assume the input file is well-formed) or add additional checks after the `split` (and then the `float` casts need checking as well).